# how to convert sql long format to wide format

Tags: sql, format, long-integer

I have the following data input from sql query
[image]

Basiclly, the original query returns 365 rows of 24 hours dat for 1000 IDs. As the result, I'd like to put all 365 x 24 data into one row for each ID.

How should I do it?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: and *never* post pictures as samples - SO provides enough markup methods to use

Comment: I do not recommend storing data like this at all. It would make much more sense to `UNPIVOT` your 365 x 24 dataset to a 4 x 8760 (ID, Date, Hour, Value) dataset where there is one row for every hour of every day then generate a new id based on the id, date, and hour.
Otherwise you may as well iterate through each row in python and assign every value to a variable.